# Safety with CPU amount on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, memory, cpu, cpu-usage

I am trying to completely max out a Lenovo Edge 15 with an Intel(R) Core i7-4510U CPU with 8 gb of RAM( 16gb coming in the mail, also the max. It also has a Samsung evo 840 256 gb SSD. My concern is that if I go into msconfig and check number of processors and then click the drop down where 4 of them show, will adding more make the computer faster? Also, what is the amount to add if I have 4 or is there no safety issues when changing these? Right now my startup is at 1.8-3 seconds and I run a lot of web develop, app develop, video and photo editing.

Comment: the slowest part is the CPU. The U version is Dual Core CPU which is optimized for battery life. So if you compile large programs, the CPU may be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

You are not possible to set `Number of processor` more than your CPU supported via msconfig. The drop down list is dynamic generated so no worry about you are setting higher than supported. Setting those wont make your computer run faster, that is use for debugging purpose only or to fit some special application which required lesser core.

Comment: Thank you, most of what I looked up didn't say that, so this was helpful. Would you have any other suggestions for speed? Besides the ram, I think I may have maxed out the machine